# How to convert column values present in date/custom/general formats in a PySpark/Pandas dataframe into a Date Format?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a dataframe which has a column consisting of Date values present in multiple formats (shown as custom/general/date in Excel) like what you can see in the "Before" column below:

[image]

They all are originally date values only, but have somewhere got modified into different formats in the input CSV files that I got.

***My objective is to convert the values into "DD/MM/YYYY" format that you can see in the "After" column.***

I'm reading this as a Pandas/Spark dataframe since there are thousands of such values in the column for which this change has to be effected.

I tried doing the following, but it isn't resulting into the correct "DD/MM/YYYY" format that I need. Moreover, some of the values are remaining unchanged too:

`df['After'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Before'], format='%d-%m-%y, errors='coerce')`

Can anyone please help with how to go about this?

Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my try:

```
df = pd.read_excel('test.xls')

df['ADATE'] = pd.to_datetime(pd.to_numeric(df['A'],errors='coerce'), unit='D', origin='1899-12-30').fillna(pd.to_datetime(df['A'],errors='coerce'))


print(df)
```

**output** (how last line will be readed???)

```
             A                   ADATE
0    43746.39028 2019-10-08 09:22:00.192
1          43735 2019-09-27 00:00:00.000
2  1/1/2021 0:00 2021-01-01 00:00:00.000
3        50:11.0                     NaT
```

**EDIT**

Using ".dt.strftime('%d/%m/%Y')" you use the desired format, remembering that this will change the type.

```
df['ADATE'] = pd.to_datetime(pd.to_numeric(df['A'],errors='coerce'), unit='D', origin='1899-12-30').fillna(pd.to_datetime(df['A'],errors='coerce')).dt.strftime('%d/%m/%Y')
```

Comment: This is working well to convert all the values into a uniform format. However, I'll need a slight tweak in this format. Can we have it like exactly like this? 
27/09/2019

Comment: The date needs to be in DD/MM/YYYY format. And the time values can be eliminated.

Comment: Yes, but this will make the column contain strings again. Just add ".dt.strftime('%d/%m/%Y')" to second code line. Like this: df['ADATE'] = pd.to_datetime(pd.to_numeric(df['A'],errors='coerce'), unit='D', origin='1899-12-30').fillna(pd.to_datetime(df['A'],errors='coerce')).dt.strftime('%d/%m/%Y')

Comment: This works! Got it in the format that I wanted. You may want to edit and add ".dt.strftime('%d/%m/%Y')" in the main answer you provided. Thanks! :)